# Problem with using laravel Auth::logoutOtherDevices

Tags: laravel, session

I want to use `Laravel` `Auth::logoutOtherDevices`. I added  `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` to `$middlewareGroups` => `web` in `kernal`.
When I use this in login function :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
    ], $request->has('remember'));

    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->input('password'));
}
```

All passwords in my database change and I can't login with other accounts. :|
 Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Before getting started, you should make sure that the 
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession middleware is present and un-commented in your App\Http\Kernel class' web middleware group:

```
'web' => [
// ...
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
// ...
```

],

Then, you may use the logoutOtherDevices method provided by the Auth facade. This method requires the user to confirm their current password, which your application should accept through an input form

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::logoutOtherDevices($currentPassword);

Comment: :| I told in question, I added `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class`  in `kernal`. look at my code. I did all of your suggestions before.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `sendLoginResponse` method after attempt as it is inside of **AuthenticateUsers** trait, because `sendLoginResponse` implements `$request->session()->regenerate();` in it.

A clean implementation of your purpose is to leave trait's `login` method intact and create `authenticated` method in the controller that has **AuthenticateUsers** trait and add below code it in.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->get('password'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Where I have to add this method? Can you explain more!

Comment: !I added to loginController but not happend

Comment: I'm using this in a lot of projects and it works perfectly. Have you cleared your customized login method?

Comment: Where should I add? in login controller ?

Comment: I added authenticated in login controller but not happend !:(

Comment: Yes. In your loginController, remove `login` method and add `authenticated` method that I wrote in the answer.

Comment: The trick for me was to use `AuthenticateUsers trait`  in my conttroller as it was on a custom controller